# angular2-highcharts Highcharts exporting module

Tags: highcharts, angular

How do I include the exporting module into an angular2 app?

I have tried adding the below script to the index.html but nothing happens.

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Angular CLI 1.0-RC.1 and latest angular2-highcharts, this is working for me (see also this on-going discussion for the recommended solution https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/issues/156):

```
npm install --save angular2-highcharts 
npm install --save @types/highcharts
```

In typings.d.ts add: `declare var require: any;`

Then in app.module.ts:

```
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import {HighchartsStatic} from 'angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService';
export function highchartsFactory() {
  var hc = require('highcharts');
  var hcm = require('highcharts/highcharts-more');
  var exp = require('highcharts/modules/exporting');

  hcm(hc);
  exp(hc);
  return hc;
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ChartModule
  ],
  providers: [{provide: HighchartsStatic, useFactory: highchartsFactory}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Old answer for earlier version:

If you use angular-cli (webpack), and angular2-highcharts, this worked for me:

```
import {Highcharts} from 'angular2-highcharts';
require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);
```

Comment: actually only need: require('highcharts/modules/exporting')

Answer (score -1):

Create a directive, `HighchartsExporting`, for example here is one for Highcharts:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[ng2-highcharts]',
    exportAs: 'ng2Highcharts'
})
export class Ng2Highcharts implements OnDestroy {
    hostElement: ElementRef;
    pChart: HighchartsChartObject;
    constructor(ele: ElementRef) {
        this.hostElement = ele;
    }

    @Input('ng2-highcharts') set options(opt: HighchartsOptions) {
        if (!opt) {
            console.log('No valid options...');
            console.log(opt);
            return;
        }
        if (opt.series || opt.data) {
            if (this.pChart) {
                this.pChart.destroy();
            }
            if (!opt.chart) {
                opt.chart = {};
            }
            opt.chart.renderTo = this.hostElement.nativeElement;
            this.pChart = new Highcharts.Chart(opt);
        } else {
            console.log('No valid options...');
            console.dir(opt);
        }
    }


    public get chart() : HighchartsChartObject {
        return this.pChart;
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.pChart) {
            this.pChart.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this does not answer the question at all - this just shows how to include highchart chart